# How to permanently disable laptop keyboard in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, hardware

I have just started using Linux based os.My laptop keyboard is malfunctioning and any key gets pressed randomly.

Earlier when I was using Windows I disabled the in-built keyboard by installing a wrong driver for the in-built keyboard and used to work using a usb keyboard attached.

How can I do something similar in linux and disable the in-built keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to permanently disable the keyboard you can do so in the BIOS.

If you do not want to disable it from the BIOS. You can do the following :

First, list the devices your X sees:

```
xinput --list
"Virtual core pointer"  id=0    [XPointer]
"Virtual core keyboard" id=1    [XKeyboard]
"Keyboard2"     id=2    [XExtensionKeyboard]
"Mouse2"        id=3    [XExtensionKeyboard]
```

Then disable your keyboard :

```
xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Disabled" 8 0
```

And to enable :

```
xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Enabled" 8 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `xinput`, another option is to create your own `xorg.conf` file (usually `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, but Mint may prefer somewhere else). This will cause the X server to ignore it right when the X server starts, no additional action necessary. It should look something like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier         "disable broken device"
   MatchIsKeyboard    "on"
   MatchProduct       "full product name from 'xinput list'"
   Option             "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Also see e.g. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/335687/disabling-an-dev-inputx-input-device-on-ubuntu-linux) question. More details on available options can be found with `man xorg.conf`.